Error Appium 2: could not start a new session
I'm trying to migrate my appium project from intellidj paid to Intellijd Comunity, in my previous project my automation ran successfully but when I used Intellidj community I got this error.
org.openqa.selenium.sessionnotcreatedexception: could not start a new session. possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
I try all the solutions:
1.- I created a new emulated using android 28
2.- I used manager.dependecy in POM
3.- I created New project but I got similar error

This error is due to an incompatibility between the version of selenium and java. What I did was first update the version of appium, then lower the version of java-client from 9 to 8.6 in other words:
step 1: Enter the POM of the project and download the version of the java-client de:
io.appium
java-client
9.1.0
llevalo a :
io.appium
java-client
8.6.0

This error is due to an incompatibility between the version of selenium and java. What I did was first update the version of appium, then lower the version of java-client from 9 to 8.6 in other words:
Step 1: Enter the POM of the project and download the version of the java-client from:
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>9.1.0</version>

To:
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>8.6.0</version>

and your test haven't any problem.
